# Finding correlation between multiple rows of a data frame with another multiple rows within the same data frame

Tags: r

The sample data set is as follows:

```
samp_data=data.frame(str=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),week=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4),var1=c(1,3,4,1,1,3,1,1,1,1,1,1),var2=c(2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2))

> samp_data
   str week var1 var2
1    1    1    1    2
2    1    2    3    2
3    1    3    4    2
4    1    4    1    2
5    2    1    1    2
6    2    2    3    2
7    2    3    1    2
8    2    4    1    2
9    3    1    1    2
10   3    2    1    2
11   3    3    1    2
12   3    4    1    2
```

What i want to do is to find the correlation of every store with every other store in the data frame, the only catch is that every store has multiple rows. So what i want is something like this

```
require(energy)
DCOR(samp_data[samp_data$str==1,c("var1")],samp_data[samp_data$str==2,c("var1")])

$dCov
[1] 0.5303301

$dCor
[1] 0.5639143

$dVarX
[1] 1.179248

$dVarY
[1] 0.75
```

where as you can see i am finding the correlation between all rows having store 1 with all rows having store 2.

I dont want to use the for loop for this exercise, i thought of diag function but i guess it calculates row by row, is there a way i can do this using apply or some similar fast paced function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `combn` as follows,

```
combn(unique(samp_data$str), 2, function(i) 
        cor(samp_data$var1[samp_data$str == i[1]], samp_data$var1[samp_data$str == i[2]]))
```

Comment: That pretty much does what is required the only thing is that if i want to select top 5 stores having the highest correlation with store 2 then how do I find those values and the store numbers. When i used the above formula for my dataset containing 4 stores i get 0.5169370 0.3946689 0.3859648 0.7030863 0.8703083 0.8592434. Now this is 4C2 combinations of the stores present, but if i want to find out the top two stores which have highest correlation with store 2 then how do i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a `dplyr` and `tidyr` way:

```
library(tidyverse)
samp_data %>% 
  select(str, var1) %>% 
  group_by(str) %>% 
  mutate(n=1:n()) %>% 
  spread(str, var1 ) %>% 
  select(-n) %>% 
  cor(.)
          1         2  3
1 1.0000000 0.3333333 NA
2 0.3333333 1.0000000 NA
3        NA        NA  1
```

Comment: That is excatly what i need, the only minor hiccup is that i want to use the dcor function instead of the cor function due to some specific requirement. The problem is dcor function expects two arguments i.e. the variables between which the correlation needs to be calculated and that is why this code if failing with dcor function